# Generate Treeview in jquery

Tags: jquery, treeview, iteration, jstree

I want to generate a treeview using jstree. In this treeview the user have the option to change the structure of treeview, like adding parents, adding child, renaming the nodes etc. It must be expandable, collapsable and with checkbox.

it looks like this:
[sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuHYN.png)

Have searched a lot, but couldn't find any. Only way out is to ask question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code...

```
$('#jstree_demo').jstree({
  "core" : {
    "animation" : 0,
    "check_callback" : true,
    "themes" : { "stripes" : true },
    'data' : {
      'url' : function (node) {
        return node.id === '#' ?
          'ajax_demo_roots.json' : 'ajax_demo_children.json';
      },
      'data' : function (node) {
        return { 'id' : node.id };
      }
    }
  },
  "types" : {
    "#" : {
      "max_children" : 1,
      "max_depth" : 4,
      "valid_children" : ["root"]
    },
    "root" : {
      "icon" : "/static/3.3.0/assets/images/tree_icon.png",
      "valid_children" : ["default"]
    },
    "default" : {
      "valid_children" : ["default","file"]
    },
    "file" : {
      "icon" : "glyphicon glyphicon-file",
      "valid_children" : []
    }
  },
  "plugins" : [
    "contextmenu", "dnd", "search",
    "state", "types", "wholerow"
  ]
});
```

More details can be found [here](https://www.jstree.com/demo/)

*Hope this helps....*